# IE8 will report error about for in without declaring var item?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, for-loop

Like :

```
var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
var html = value = '';

for(item in result)
{

}
```

`response` is a json response.

It stops at `for..` in IE8.

How to fix that?

**EDIT**

I got the same error when running:

```
result = [1,2,3];
for(item in result)
{
...
}
```

Comment: never heard of that, what is the code you're trying to use?

Comment: Elaborate on what you expect it to do, and what it is doing instead.

Comment: I think (result) is not evaluatable ? so it might be null or undefined

Comment: I tried `typeof result`,which is "object"

Comment: Just checking, but you are accessing the result items via _result[item]_ right?

Also, are you certain that _response_ is valid JSON?

Comment: If you already have IE 8 there, then you have a script debugger at hand already. Just press F12 and debug your snippet to find the actual cause.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel ,I just used IE8 debugger to find that it doesn't support `for .. in` clause

Comment: Show us the JSON object, please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested the code from [JavaScript For...In Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_loop_for_in.asp) in IE8, no issue.

Definitely not an issue of the loop (not working in IE8) but what is in the 'result' object.

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue.

In IE8 (not sure about other IE versions) the word "item" somehow is a reserved word or something.

This will work:

```
var item;
for(item in result)
{
...
}
```

This will not (if `item` is not declared):

```
for(item in result)
{
...
}
```

This will work:

```
for(_item in result)
{
...
}
```

Comment: It turns out that it's because of lack of this statement:`var item;`.Have you met this?

Comment: See my findings in my update post. 'item' is indeed the culprit.

Comment: I would never have found out also if you didn't highlight the 'var item' in your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `item` explicitly with `var`.  The standard idiom for using `for..in` is as follows and should only be used for iteration over objects (not arrays):

```
for ( var item in result ) {
    if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
        // loop body goes here
    }
}
```